# xcodebuild failed to build workspace with scheme. Reason - There is nothing to test

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I have app with UITests target in Xcode 8.
I can run tests fine using Xcode. Now m trying to run them using command line.

> xcodebuild test build-for-testing test-without-building -workspace
>   a.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme testtargetscheme -destination
>   id=deviceuid -only-testing:StartupTestSuite

But it fails with: xcodebuild failed to build workspace with scheme. Reason - There is nothing to test.
I have checked scheme settings and made sure it does have tests enabled. I also tried above command with normal app run scheme, for which also I have test configured properly.

Any ideas?